# How do I change NSFetchResultController array that holds my objects to different indexes for my objects?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a method that I use to hold and move cells in my table view to different index that looks like this:

```
- (void)moveTableView:(FMMoveTableView *)tableView moveRowFromIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath { 
NSArray *allObjects = [self.fetchedResultController fetchedObjects];
//array to hold the new order    
NSMutableArray * arrayCorectOrder = [NSMutableArray new];
//the target object that is in the index we are moving from
Target *target = [self.fetchedResultController objectAtIndexPath:fromIndexPath];
 }
```

i have a coreDataStack class that takes care of all the core data stuff (creating a singelton), it looks like this:

```
#import "CoreDataStack.h"

@implementation CoreDataStack

#pragma mark - Core Data stack

@synthesize managedObjectContext = _managedObjectContext;
@synthesize managedObjectModel = _managedObjectModel;
@synthesize persistentStoreCoordinator = _persistentStoreCoordinator;

+ (instancetype)defaultStack {

    static CoreDataStack *defaultStack;
    static dispatch_once_t onceTocken;
    dispatch_once (&onceTocken, ^{
        defaultStack = [[self alloc] init];
    });

    return defaultStack;
}


- (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory {
    // The directory the application uses to store the Core Data store file. This code uses a directory named "digitalCrown.Lister" in the application's documents directory.
    return [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
}

- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel {
    // The managed object model for the application. It is a fatal error for the application not to be able to find and load its model.
    if (_managedObjectModel != nil) {
        return _managedObjectModel;
    }
    NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"Lister" withExtension:@"momd"];
    _managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];
    return _managedObjectModel;
}

- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator {
    // The persistent store coordinator for the application. This implementation creates and return a coordinator, having added the store for the application to it.
    if (_persistentStoreCoordinator != nil) {
        return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
    }

    // Create the coordinator and store

    _persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];
    NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Lister.sqlite"];
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSString *failureReason = @"There was an error creating or loading the application's saved data.";
    if (![_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:nil error:&error]) {
        // Report any error we got.
        NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
        dict[NSLocalizedDescriptionKey] = @"Failed to initialize the application's saved data";
        dict[NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey] = failureReason;
        dict[NSUnderlyingErrorKey] = error;
        error = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"YOUR_ERROR_DOMAIN" code:9999 userInfo:dict];
        // Replace this with code to handle the error appropriately.
        // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }

    return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
}


- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext {
    // Returns the managed object context for the application (which is already bound to the persistent store coordinator for the application.)
    if (_managedObjectContext != nil) {
        return _managedObjectContext;
    }

    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
    if (!coordinator) {
        return nil;
    }
    _managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
    [_managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
    return _managedObjectContext;
}

#pragma mark - Core Data Saving support

- (void)saveContext {
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
    if (managedObjectContext != nil) {
        NSError *error = nil;
        if ([managedObjectContext hasChanges] && ![managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            abort();
        }
    }
}


@end
```

and whenever i add new object to core data i do it this way:

```
- (void)insertTeget {

    CoreDataStack *stack = [CoreDataStack defaultStack];
    Target *target = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Target" inManagedObjectContext:stack.managedObjectContext];
    if (self.myTextView.text != nil) {
        target.body = self.myTextView.text;
        target.time = [NSDate date];
    }

    [stack saveContext];

}
```

in the table view when I'm fetching the data i do it this way:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"StackTableViewCell";

    Target *target = [self.fetchedResultController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    StackTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (!cell)
    {
        NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"StackTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    cell.cellLabel.text = target.body;

    cell.cellLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Candara-Bold" size:20];

    cell.showsReorderControl = YES;



    // Configure the cell...

    return cell;
}
```

this is my fetchresultconroller/fetch request config in the table view controller class:

```
- (NSFetchRequest *)targetsFetchRequest {

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Target"];
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"time" ascending:YES];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
    return fetchRequest;
}


- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultController {

    if (_fetchedResultController != nil) {
        return _fetchedResultController;
    }

    CoreDataStack *stack = [CoreDataStack defaultStack];

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [self targetsFetchRequest];

    _fetchedResultController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:stack.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];

    _fetchedResultController.delegate = self;

    return _fetchedResultController;

}
```

and now I wand to check if the order was changed so I need to change the order in the database...

how do I do this?

thanks!

Comment: What sort order have you specified in your fetched results controller configuration?  If you are allowing the user to reorder the rows, you need to have an attribute (eg. 'index' or 'sortOrder') on your entity that you can amend to reflect the chosen order, and you should use this as the key for sorting in the FRC.

Comment: to be honest im really a beginner so I don't know exactly to answer your question so i just added more explanations to my question that maybe will help you understand more :)

Comment: Thanks. Can you also add the code where you create and configure the fetchedResultsController?

Comment: OK, so your FRC is configured to sort using the `time` attribute.  If you want to allow the user to override this, and move the rows around, then you will need to use a different sort order.  (Or I suppose you could amend the `time` attribute for the object to get it to the correct indexPath.  For example, if you are moving from row 6 to row 3, you would need `time` to be greater than the time for row 2, but less than the time for row 3.)

Comment: @pbasdf is there a chance for an answer with code ? I'm not sure it's important for me to save the objects sorted by time, but when i show the table view its important for me to present it by time it was created since this is a queue...Unless the user wants to change the order manually...I really need help here :/

Comment: I don't have any suitable code I can just cut and paste, but I will put down some thoughts and suggestions in an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my comments, the fetched results controller bases the indexPath for each object on the sort order of the underlying fetch - in your case `time`.  If you want the user to be able to override this, and reorder the rows, then change the FRC to use a different sort order.  Add a new attribute (of date type) to your entity, named `sortTime`, and amend the `targetsFetchRequest` method to use `sortTime` as the sort key.

Whenever you add a new `Target`, set the `sortTime` at the same time.  When it comes to reordering the rows, set the value of `sortTime` to ensure that the FRC places the Target at the new indexPath.  Something like this:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)destinationIndexPath {
    Target *targetToMove = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:sourceIndexPath];
    if (destinationIndexPath.row == 0) {
        // to move to row 0, the new sortTime can be any value
        // that is  less than the sortTime of the Target currently at
        // row 0
        Target *targetAtRow0 = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:destinationIndexPath];
        targetToMove.sortTime = [targetAtRow0.sortTime dateByAddingTimeInterval:-1];
    } else {
        // for any other row, set the sortTime to be half way 
        // between the sortTime for the row before the new position
        // and the sortTime for the row at the new position
        Target *targetBefore = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:(destinationIndexPath.row-1) inSection:destinationIndexPath.section]];
        Target *targetAfter = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:destinationIndexPath];
        double lowerTimeInterval = [targetBefore.sortTime timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
        double upperTimeInterval = [targetAfter.sortTime timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
        double newInterval = (lowerTimeInterval + upperTimeInterval)/2;
        NSDate *newSortTime = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:newInterval];
        targetToMove.sortTime = newSortTime;
    }
    NSError *error;
    if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"SaveContext: error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }
}
```

This should trigger your FRC delegate methods to perform the necessary table view updates.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you consider adding another attribute to your Entity `Target`, perhaps call it "`sortOrder`"?

When you fetch your results, consider sorting by `sortOrder` instead.

To make this work, you will need to set the `sortOrder` value at the time you create each entity. This should be relatively simple... complete a count of the `fetchedResults` prior to creating the entity, assume that your next `sortOrder` value will equal the count value plus 1.

When you move a row in the tableview, you can use code to reassign the `sortOrder` value of affected cells to equal the `indexPath.row` property.

Once saved, your new sort order should persist.